# SQL - How to retrieve the first free number in a range of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, `TblClient`.
The 2 important columns are: `ClientID` (PK, increment) and `ClientNumber`.

We can add new clients, and the `ClientID` is auto assigned, but the `ClientNumber` can be chosen.

We want to make a "suggestion" for the `ClientNumber`, but the user can decide to input their own number and not take our suggestion.

The suggestion must be he first available `ClientNumber` that is bigger than 2200 (first `ClientNumber` is 2200).

We do this because if a user inputs a manual number, like 5000, when the last inserted one is 2500, we don't wont the next "suggestion" to be 5001, but 2501.

What is the correct way to return this number with a query?

Thank you!

Comment: You probably want to maintain a table of available numbers. The suggestion will be the smallest available number, and any manually-selected number will be verified against what is available. Numbers, once taken, will either be marked off or deleted from the table of available numbers. Just be careful in the design to ensure that the numbers are either allocated atomically or properly reserved - you don't want two concurrent users accepting the same suggestion or picking the same number manually at the same time as each other.

Comment: Thank you for this point, but in our use case, this is an internal software, and only 1 or 2 people are allowed to add new clients, and the rate that clients are added is maybe once per week, so it would be almost impossible that the only 2 people that are allowed, do this at the same time without communicating! But it is something I will discuss internally for sure, because even if it won't happen probably, it's best practice to implement a check that does prevent this

Comment: indeed, the situation may seem highly unlikely, but unless the application is itself limited to one running instance, then it is better to incorporate some logic that allows the database to maintain consistency. The distribution of such unlikely cases is also usually not random - clients may only come in once a week, but if one user forgets to add a client straightaway, they may be prompted to do so by the other user mentioning another new client, and then they both set about simultaneously to add new clients. Communication between the users makes the dangerous case more likely.

Comment: Yes indeed, that is a good point and we will implement a check to avoid this, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could address it with a self-left join antipattern, like so:

```
select coalesce(min(c.ClientNumber) + 1, 2200) first_available_client_id
from tblclient c
left join tblclient c_free on c_free.ClientNumber = c.ClientNumber + 1
where c_free.ClientID is null
```

Explanation: the `left join` attempts to combine each record with another record that has the next client number. Then, the `where` clause filters non-matching joins, which means on records where the next client number is not yet used in the table. Finally, aggregate function `min(...) + 1` returns the first available client number. The `coalesce()` function is there to return `2200` when the table is empty.

For efficiency, you want an index on `ClientNumber` (it should already be there since you want this column to be unique).

Another option that avoids the use of aggregation is:

```
select c.ClientNumber + 1 first_available_client_id
from tblclient c
left join tblclient c_free on c_free.ClientNumber = c.ClientNumber + 1
where c_free.ClientID is null
order by c.ClientNumber
limit 1
```

However this option does not handle the case when the table is empty.

Comment: This solution does not intrinsically enforce the 2200 lower limit (although I accept it will once the table is primed with an initial value). It also has the potential to become somewhat inefficient over time, as the number of existing rows proliferate.

Comment: to enforce the 2200 limit, I just add "WHERE c_free.ClientID is null AND c.ClientNumber > 2200" and that fixes it, but I'm wondering which of these 2 solution is best/most efficient? They both seem to be working fine, which one should I keep?

Comment: @AJ989: if you are dealing with a large number of records, I would advocate for the second, that avoids the use of aggregation.

Comment: @Steve: I updated my answer for a solution when the table is empty (but that only works in the first solution).

Comment: @GMB ok great, I don't think a couple of thousands records are too large as number of records, but if the performance of both is pretty much the same, then yes, I can use the second one to avoid aggregation

Comment: @GMB, it's only a nitpick, but that solution still requires the table to be primed - where no row exists and the table is empty, the coalesce in the select (designed only for this) will never be invoked. I'd also be surprised if there is any difference in performance in these two cases - the join will be by far the most expensive operation, and the performance of each of the min-aggregating and ordering-then-limiting alternatives is likely to be similar (in theory, the scan for the minimum would be far faster than the ordering, but the database engine is likely to recognise the equivalence).

Comment: @Steve: the way the first query is built, it *will* return a record when the table is empty. [See this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGp2d1suoG8PR9p6yYKJdH/0).

Comment: @GMB, agreed and my apologies. The coalesce follows an aggregate operation that will return a null row for the empty set!

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the ClientNumber to the rank of the ClientNumber and then it would be just the case of picking the first row where they don't match. Something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
  ClientNumber
  ,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ClientNumber) + 2199 AS r
FROM t
WHERE ClientNumber >= 2200)
SELECT
  r
FROM cte
WHERE r != ClientNumber
ORDER BY r
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists`, but you have to be very careful to check for the number being greater than 2200:

```
select coalesce(min(c.ClientNumber) + 1, 2200) as next_available
from tblclient c
where not exists (select 1
                  from tblclient c2
                  where c2.clientNumber = c.clientNumber + 1 
                 ) and
      c.clientNumber >= 2200;
```

**Very importantly**:  This works even when the custom client numbers are less than 2200.  The other solutions do not seem to take this into account.